# Adding a csv generated dropdown menu to amcharts

Tags: javascript, d3.js, drop-down-menu, amcharts, finance

I am new to javascript and am working on an application which would allow someone to view a plot for data using amCharts. I had tried Dash by Plotly but unfortunately on a shared platform I couldnt run it as it consumed more resources than expected. The challenge I have been having is linking the dropdown menu to the amCharts. I tried linking them up using the code below but returned errors saying value is not known. I have the following blocks of code can someone assist in linking them up.

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<style>
#dropdown {
  width : 100%;
  height  : auto;
}
#chartdiv {
  width : 100%;
  height  : 500px;
}
</style>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <script src="amcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="serial.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="amstock.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="plugins/dataloader/dataloader.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/export/export.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<script>
        <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
<script>

  d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
    var select = d3.select("body")
      .append("div")
      .append("select")

    select
      .on("change", function(d) {
        var value = d3.select(this).property("value");
      });

    select.selectAll("option")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
        .append("option")
        .attr("value", function (d) { return d.value; })
        .text(function (d) { return d.label; });

  });
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
  "path": "/amcharts/",
  "type": "stock",
  "theme": "light",
  "dataSets": [ {
    "title": value,
    "fieldMappings": [ {
      "fromField": "Open",
      "toField": "open"
    }, {
      "fromField": "High",
      "toField": "high"
    }, {
      "fromField": "Low",
      "toField": "low"
    }, {
      "fromField": "Close",
      "toField": "close"
    }, {
      "fromField": "Volume",
      "toField": "volume"
    } ],
    "compared": false,
    "categoryField": "Date",

    /**
     * data loader for data set data
     */
    "dataLoader": {
      "url": "http://www.google.com/finance/historical?q="+value+":ADBE&startdate=Jan+01%2C+2009&enddate=Aug+2%2C+2012&output=csv",
      "format": "csv",
      "showCurtain": true,
      "showErrors": true,
      "async": true,
      "reverse": false,
      "delimiter": ",",
      "useColumnNames": true
    },

  }],

  "panels": [ {
    "showCategoryAxis": false,
    "title": "Value",
    "percentHeight": 70,
    "stockGraphs": [ {
        "type": "line",
        "id": "g1",
        /*"openField": "open",
        "closeField": "close",
        "highField": "high",
        "lowField": "low",*/
        "valueField": "close",
        "lineColor": "#db4c3c",
        "fillColors": "#fff",
        "negativeLineColor": "#db4c3c",
        "negativeFillColors": "#db4c3c",
        "fillAlphas": 0,
        "comparedGraphLineThickness": 2,
        "columnWidth": 0.7,
        "useDataSetColors": false,
        "comparable": true,
        "compareField": "close",
        "showBalloon": false,
        "proCandlesticks": true
      } ],
    "stockLegend": {
      "periodValueTextComparing": "[[percents.value.close]]%",
      "periodValueTextRegular": "[[value.close]]"
    }
  }, {
    "title": "Volume",
    "percentHeight": 30,
    "stockGraphs": [ {
      "valueField": "volume",
      "type": "column",
      "showBalloon": false,
      "fillAlphas": 1,
       "lineColor": "#db4c3c",
       "fillColors": "#db4c3c",
       "negativeLineColor": "#db4c3c",
       "negativeFillColors": "#db4c3c"
    } ],
    "stockLegend": {
      "periodValueTextRegular": "[[value.close]]"
    }
  } ],

  "chartScrollbarSettings": {
    "graph": "g1"
  },

  "chartCursorSettings": {
    "valueBalloonsEnabled": true,
    "fullWidth": true,
    "cursorAlpha": 0.1,
    "valueLineBalloonEnabled": true,
    "valueLineEnabled": true,
    "valueLineAlpha": 0.5
  },

  "periodSelector": {
    "position": "left",
    "periods": [ {
      "period": "MM",
      "selected": true,
      "count": 1,
      "label": "1 month"
    }, {
      "period": "YYYY",
      "count": 1,
      "label": "1 year"
    },{
      "period": "YYYY",
      "count": 2,
      "label": "2 year"
    },{
      "period": "YTD",
      "label": "YTD"
    }, {
      "period": "MAX",
      "label": "MAX"
    } ]
  },

  "dataSetSelector": {
    "position": "left"
  },

  "export": {
    "enabled": true
  }
} );
</script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

The trick is retaining the value of the dropdown and appending it to the url. The other thing is it possible to create a call back function to update the plot whenever the dropdown is changed. The contents of the dropdown are

```
name,ticker
apple, AAPL
google,googl
microsoft,msft
```

The first row being the header row with column names. The intention is not to hard code the dataset and the dropdown to allow someone without any knowledge to change add a dataset to the list. Its not necessarily financial data but also healthcare and other forms. chose this as a working example coz it was nearest.

Answer (score 0):

`value` isn't defined by the time `AmCharts.makeChart` is called due to the fact that the csv method is asynchronous. You'll want to adjust your setup so that your csv callback creates the initial chart with a default value, e.g.

```
  var chart;
  d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
    // ... other code ...

    var value = data[0].ticker; //for this particular use case - update to the appropriate csv column name as needed
    chart = AmCharts.makeChart("...", {
       // ... rest of your config as usual, including the now defined value variable
    });

  });
```

To make the dropdown update the chart, you need to modify the chart instance's dataLoader url then call the [`loadData`](https://github.com/amcharts/dataloader/#user-content-manually-triggering-a-reload-of-all-data) method during the change callback:

```
select
  .on("change", function(d) {
    var value = d3.select(this).property("value");
    chart.dataSets[0].dataLoader.url = /* modify the url string here */
    chart.dataSets[0].dataLoader.loadData(); //reload the data with new URL value
  });
```

Comment: The first part I got it pretty well. Now the last part on the callback, does the modification have to be the url itself containing the selected ticker. more specific does the function have to be 'chart.dataSets[0].dataLoader.url = "http://www.google.com/finance/historical?q="+value+":ADBE&startdate=Jan+01%2C+2009&enddate=Aug+2%2C+2012&output=csv" ' where value is the new value. Then the issue of modifying the dataloader, is it making it a function that stands on its own. say at the top and is called in the code and callback

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Whatever you're doing, you have to modify/update the dataLoader's url string if you want to change it to reflect the currently selected dropdown then call loadData to refresh the chart with the new url. You can certainly abstract that process into another function if you want, just so as long as the function has access to the chart object, scope-wise. If that still doesn't help, update your question with your current code that more clearly illustrates what you're trying to do.